What are the most popular and efficient algorithms to detect image inpainting?
There are many algorithms to do forensics analysis such as steganalysis. What are the most popular and efficient algorithms to detect image inpainting? Not just detecting some copy-move or splicing and not about detecting steganorgraphy. Please provide all the material that could demonstrate and implement these algorithms in detail.
